# SQL select single row number x only

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-order-by, sql-limit

For processing SQL data in VBA I want to use a loop (For...Next) that reads line by line from a SQL database. As records were deleted the ID column has gaps. The table looks for example like this:

```
ID   Value
1    Peter
3    Paul
4    Mary
9    George
```

Having four lines I would like to run

```
For i = 1 to 4
   SELECT ???
Next i
```

of course a "For each" would do good, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 4 rows, then use `order by` and `top` - or a `fetch clause`:

```
select top(4) t.*
from mytable t
order by id
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by id
offset 0 rows fetch first 4 rows only
```

You can then iterate through the resultset in your application.

If, on the other hand, you want the 4th row only, then just change the `fetch` clause:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by id
offset 3 rows fetch next 1 row only
```

Comment: that line "offset 3 rows fetch next 1 row only"  does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read row by row, you can just walk through the result set.  But if you really need to enumerate the values, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum, t.*
from t;
```

`seqnum` is then guaranteed to be an incrementing value with no gaps that starts at 1.

EDIT:

If you want to select a particular row, you *could* use `row_number()` with a subquery or CTE:

```
select t.*
from (select row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum, t.*
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 10;
```

But the recommended method would be `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by id 
offset 9 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Thanks. However I can not add the required WHERE then. 



select row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum, t.*
from t
WHERE seqnum = 10


fails

Comment: The row_number is pretty useful when reading all lines and processing them in the application.  Thanks